# Собранный проект не запускается в Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Собрал проект в **Qt5.10**, сборщик **mingw530_32**.

В общем установил C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\vcredist **vcredist_msvc2015_x86.exe**

Закинул в сборку **ВСЕ** (из папки C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\mingw53_32\bin) библиотеки :

```
libEGL.dll
libEGLd.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libGLESv2.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
opengl32sw.dll
PCANBasic.dll
Qt5Bluetooth.dll
Qt5Concurrent.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5DBus.dll
Qt5Designer.dll
Qt5DesignerComponents.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Help.dll
Qt5Location.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll
Qt5MultimediaQuick.dll
Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Nfc.dll
Qt5OpenGL.dll
Qt5Positioning.dll
Qt5PrintSupport.dll
Qt5Qml.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5QuickControls2.dll
Qt5QuickParticles.dll
Qt5QuickTemplates2.dll
Qt5QuickTest.dll
Qt5QuickWidgets.dll
Qt5Scxml.dll
Qt5Sensors.dll
Qt5SerialBus.dll
Qt5SerialPort.dll
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Svg.dll
Qt5Test.dll
Qt5TextToSpeech.dll
Qt5WebChannel.dll
Qt5WebSockets.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
Qt5WinExtras.dll
Qt5Xml.dll
Qt5XmlPatterns.dll
Qt53DAnimation.dll
Qt53DCore.dll
Qt53DExtras.dll
Qt53DInput.dll
Qt53DLogic.dll
Qt53DQuick.dll
Qt53DQuickAnimation.dll
Qt53DQuickExtras.dll
Qt53DQuickInput.dll
Qt53DQuickRender.dll
Qt53DQuickScene2D.dll
 Qt53DRender.dll
```

Еще добавил библиотеки  из C:\Qt\Qt5.10.1\5.10.1\mingw53_32\plugins\platforms

```
qminimal.dll
qoffscreen.dll
qwindows.dll
```

Снова не заработало (даже ошибки не поменял)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Положите в папку с бинарником файл `/platforms/qwindows`, он лежит в папке с бинарями Qt в папке `/plugins`.

Как второй и теоретически более правильный вариант - использовать windeplowqt, но он тащит много лишнего.

Comment: только что попробовал не сработало

Comment: если ошибка со скриншота осталась, то плагин qwindows вы положили не туда, где он должен быть

Comment: добавил "копированную картинку"

Comment: перечитайте мой ответ. вы положили `qwindows.dll` в корень папки с бинарником, а надо в папку `/platforms`